# Pandas Groupby For Missing Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (actual df contains million rows), consisting of data for Week 1,2 and 3. If the Qty is 0 for that week, then the rows are not present. For example, Product A qty=0 for Week 2, thus there is no Week 2 row shown in the dataframe.

| Product | Week | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 3 | 10 |
| B | 2 | 10 |
| B | 2 | 10 |

I want to groupby into this dataframe showing the qty for each week including when Qty=0. How to achieve this? Thank you.

| Product | Week | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 20 |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 10 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 20 |
| B | 3 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

```
#Groupby and sum
df1=df.groupby(['Product','Week'])['Qty'].sum().to_frame()

#reindex, multiindex
df1.reindex( pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index.levels[0], 
df['Week'].unique()], names=['Product', 'Week']),fill_value=0).reset_index()





    Product  Week  Qty
0       A     1   20
1       A     3   10
2       A     2    0
3       B     1    0
4       B     3    0
5       B     2   20
```

Comment: btw sir if you replace `df['Week'].unique()` with `df1.index.levels[1].unique()` the  order become exact same that op wants

Comment: Hmmm I tried your code above but it does not give the result you shown.  @wwnde

Comment: The result is missing Week 2 rows

Comment: @Mel, reset_index() should give to the result. See the edits.

Comment: @mel, one line out of the debacle `df.groupby(['Product','Week'])['Qty'].sum().to_frame().reindex( pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Product.unique(), 
df.Week.unique()], names=['Product', 'Week']),fill_value=0).sort_values(by=['Product','Week']).reset_index()`

Comment: @wwnde still do not get Week 2 rows. Hmm. did u use the same df?

Comment: What happenning? My answer is a direct replica of your output. Are there any difference you can see?